# "sudo docker push" fails with a seemingly bogus error message

Tags: docker, command, push

Here is my terminal log (Ubuntu 22.04.1, Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b):

```bash
paul@desktop:~/work/arc/code$ docker images
REPOSITORY        TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
pauljurczak/arc   latest    4f3f22791983   35 minutes ago   880MB
sub-1             latest    4f3f22791983   35 minutes ago   880MB
neo-1             latest    3dcf55bb7458   3 days ago       891MB
arc-tut           latest    3a9aee91689b   4 days ago       230MB
paul@desktop:~/work/arc/code$ sudo docker push pauljurczak/arc
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/pauljurczak/arc]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: pauljurczak/arc
paul@desktop:~/work/arc/code$ sudo docker push pauljurczak/arc:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/pauljurczak/arc]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: pauljurczak/arc
pauljurczak/arc
paul@desktop:~/work/arc/code$ sudo docker push latest
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/latest]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: latest
```

I created `pauljurczak/arc:latest` image as shown there. I'm trying to push it to my `pauljurczak/arc` repository. The error messages don't make any sense to me. Why `pauljurczak/arc` in my push command is considered a tag? Why *An image does not exist locally with the tag: latest*, while there exists several images with that tag? What is happening here? I'm following `push` command description at https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/#pushing-a-docker-container-image-to-docker-hub.

When viewing my repository with Chrome, I see this info:

[image]

That's exactly what I was doing.

---

It seems that skipping `sudo` makes it work. Why is that?

Comment: Are you using Docker Desktop on Linux?  (Why?)  If you are, then your user context and root would see different Docker daemons.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I have Docker Desktop installed and observed some weird behavior. I will remove it. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. As for the reason why Docker Desktop, I thought it would improve my experience. I'm only a very casual Docker user and didn't know better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have both Docker Desktop and the standalone Docker Engine installed.  This means you have two different Docker daemons running.  The Docker Engine one is accessible via `/var/run/docker.sock`, given appropriate permissions; Docker Desktop runs a hidden Linux virtual machine (even on native Linux) and makes a similar socket file available in your home directory.

Docker Desktop [uses the Docker CLI "context" feature](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/#context) to point `docker` at the socket in your home directory.  That configuration is also stored in a file in your home directory.

This is where `sudo` makes a difference.  When you run `sudo docker ...`, and it reads `$HOME/.docker/contexts/`, that home directory is now root's home directory, probably `/root`.  That doesn't have any of the Docker Desktop related configuration in it, and so you use the default `/var/run/docker.sock` Docker Engine socket instead.

As you note, just consistently not using `sudo` will resolve this.  (You could potentially need `sudo` to access the Docker Engine socket, which can all but trivially be used to root the host; the Docker Desktop VM is a little more isolated.)  Uninstalling Docker Desktop and making sure to only use the standalone Docker Engine on native Linux also would resolve this.